# If $a\mid b$, then $2^b \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\ 2^a-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove:

> If $a\mid b$, then $2^b \equiv 1 \pmod{2^a-1}$.

I learned wilson's theorem, fermat's little theorem. I have no idea how to provide these 2 into the prove.

Comment: You have $(m^x-1)| (m^{xy}-1)$ by factorising

Comment: This is easier than it looks and you learned how to do it *years* before you ever took a number theory course. What is $\frac {x^n -1}{x-1} $? Just replace $x $ with $2^a $ and $n$ with $\frac bn $.

Comment: Learn to search the site. Your question is a special case of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7473/11619) and covered in many other questions linked to that one.

Comment: And the basic ingredient is that for a number $q > 1$, the remainder of the division of $q^{b} - 1$ by $q^{a} - 1$ is $q^{r} - 1$, where $r$ is the remainder of the division of $b$ by $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $b = ka$, $2^b = (2^a)^k$

$\begin{align}\text{Then }2^b-1 &= (2^a)^k-1 \\&= (2^a-1)\big((2^a)^{k-1}+(2^a)^{k-2}+\cdots+2^a+1\big)\end{align}$
 and $2^a{-}1\mid 2^b{-}1$ as required.